# Docusign - how to enable organization Tab for docusign demo account?

Tags: docusignapi

My project requirement is as below:

- With out any user interaction in browser we need to generate unique URL for each user to sign the uploaded document.
- Assume we have a backend java class running in backend and we have to achieve this without any customer interaction.

Problems:

1. We are not able to follow the steps given by docusign to agree for consent via administrator. We dont see the organization Tab in our demo account.
2. It says to contact admin - who is the admin for a demo account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need User Consent or Admin Consent to sign the uploaded document. Signing is part of workflow, and signing can be done either remote or embedded. Remote Signing means DocuSign will send an email to the recipient (Signers) of the envelope and they have to complete the Signing process from the DocuSign email only. Whereas, embedded Signing is, signers have to come to your App and your App will be hosting the Signing ceremony inside your App, and generating the Signing URL using DS APIs, example of embedded Signing is available [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/embedded_signing.html) or [sample example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/embedding). In no case, you need User or Admin consent, User/Admin Consent is needed for Sender's authentication normally, where your App want to do something for them on the user's behalf, for instance send an envelope for a user, then you need the User or Admin Consent.

Admin Consent can be achieved by Organization module in DocuSign, in which you have to claim the email domains of the user in DocuSign, these users should have email (DS Username) in the claimed email domain. Using Admin Consent you cannot generate Access token for them if they belong to email domain like GMail, Yahoo, as you cannot claim their domain in DocuSign. To enable Organization in your DS Account, I would assume you would have purchased DocuSign subscription for PROD DS Account, you need to contact your PROD DS Account's Account Manager, and DS AM can enable Organization from backend for your Demo Account for your Dev purpose (Org Admin comes with extra price, so you need to check with your AM if its included in your subscription).

Comment: Thanks i was looking for the signatiure API